# How to create a window programmatically without storyboards nor xib?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Suppose you have a blank Xcode project with no storyboard, no test, no coredata and all the .xib files are gone. How do you present a simple window within AppDelegate using swift 3/4 programmatically?
I'm very new at macOS programming and I just can't figure it out.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // What the f**k do I need to do here? :/
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

Comment: I am familiar with the lifecycle methods, It's the construction of the window that's kind of abstract to me. Besides, you mentioned iOS and I'm targeting macOS, is the implementation the same?

Comment: I've deleted that as well